# How to split an input string in an integer array(c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm just started learning c++.
In Java, to split an input, you would just to have to use the split method to split the spaces from an input.
Is there any other simple way, where you can split a string input in an integer array?
I don't care about efficiency; I just want some codes that could help me understand how to split spaces from an input.

An example would be:
Input: 1 2 3 4 
Code:

```
int list[4];
list[0]=1;
list[1]=2;
list[2]=3;
list[3]=4;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ this can be handles with basically a single function call as well.

For example like this:

```
std::string input = "1 2 3 4";  // The string we should "split"

std::vector<int> output;  // Vector to contain the results of the "split"

std::istringstream istr(input);  // Temporary string stream to "read" from

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(istr),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(output));
```

References:

- [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)
- [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)
- [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

---

If the input is not already in a string, but is to be read directly from standard input `std::cin` it's even simpler (since you don't need the temporary string stream):

```
std::vector<int> output;  // Vector to contain the results of the "split"

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(output));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
  int list[4];
  for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
  {
     std::cin >> list[i];
  }

  std::cout << "list: " << list[0] << ", " << list[1] << ", " << list[2] << ", " << list[3] << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This will split the input on whitespace and assumes there are at least 4 ints in the input.

Comment: @EricChoi If you don't know about `std::cin`, then *stop right now!* [Get a couple of beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over.

Comment: cin is the basic way to get input from the terminal in C++. It comes in the header <iostream>, and the std:: is necessary unless you put "using namespace std;" at the top of the program. Using cin >> x; will get input from the terminal up to the next whitespace and try converting that stream of characters into whatever type x is. It will throw an exception if it can't make the conversion